# Intercom ring detector

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic

I'm trying to build a circuit to detect intercom rings with a logical input such as the one on an Arduino.
From a few research and testing the ring signal is often comparable to the one in a PSTN circuit
Most of the time ring signal on intercom seem to be between 20V and 90V AC.
The aim of the circuit is to convert this signal to a 3.3V peak to be detected by the logical input. The circuit should draw a minimal load of the intercom line.

the discontinued TCM1520A chip and the following Velleman product might be good starting points:
https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/0/illustrated/illustrated_assembly_manual_k8086.pdf

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The HCPL-3700 Optocoupler is ideal for this application.

Comment: That could be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> *Most of the time ring signal on intercom seem to be between 20V and
>   90V AC*

A fairly standard ring detector circuit used as an addition to POT lines is this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/89756/phone-line-ring-detection-circuit).

> *The aim of the circuit is to convert this signal to a 3.3V peak to be
>   detected by the logical input.*

The opto output can be used as a detect signal when the appropriate pull-up resistor is used - do you know how to use an opto-isolator?

Comment: I know the basics about opto-isolator. I'm not sure what would be the value of an appropriate pull-up resistor. i'm also wondering what zener diodes to use in my case. i'm also not sure of the role of D3 here.

Comment: D3 reverse protects the opto isolator's LED. D1 and D2 zeners in a telephone circuit will be about 3.9 volts and are there to stop regular audio on the line tinkling the "bell". If the actual intercom audio levels are the same as a standard telephone then 3.9 volts will be good. A pull-up value of 10 kohm is probably about right.